# Where do these Internet Explorer history files come from on Windows Azure?

Tags: internet-explorer, azure, windows-server-2008-r2, browser-history, temporary-files

When my Azure web role runs on Windows 2008 R2 (`osFamily="2"`) I see that role temporary folder contains the following files:

```
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Cookies\index.dat
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\History\History.IE5\desktop.ini
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\History\History.IE5\index.dat
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\RandomSequence\desktop.ini
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\RandomSequence\desktop.ini
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\desktop.ini
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\index.dat
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\RandomSequence\desktop.ini
C:\Resources\temp\Guid.MyRoleName\RoleTemp\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\RandomSequence\desktop.ini
```

and those files have the creation date roughly equal to the moment where my role instance `OnStart()` is invoked. I don't directly do anything that obviously uses Internet Explorer.

This is only reproduced with Windows 2008 R2 (`osFamily="2"`) and not with Windows 2008 (`osFamily="1"`).

Where do these files come from and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

Index.dat files are the indexes used by the WinINET networking component (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/19/wininet-temporary-internet-files-cache-and-explorer-folder-view.aspx for some more details) and are also used by IE and the Windows Explorer shell for tracking things like visited URLs and folders (aka "history").

The WinINET component is used by Internet Explorer, Office, the Windows Shell, and many other user-level processes.

What problem are these files causing you?

Comment: Well, first of all, I don't see why they only appeared when I switched to osFamily=2 and that makes me feel I'm not in control of anything. Then their creation definitely takes some time and that time could be used for something less useless. Finally how do I know that a million of those files doesn't appear and take up all the disk space?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is based on Win7's codebase while Windows Server 2008 is based on Vista's. It's likely that Win7 introduced use of the cache file in a scenario that Vista did not, leading to this scenario. And your assumptions that the files are "useless" and that there could be a "million of those" doesn't seem to be based on any real info?

Comment: It should actually be the other way around. I will consider those files useless until proven otherwise and I will suspect they can waste all my space until proven otherwise. I'm on the paranoid side because I don't want a monitoring alert on late Saturday night.